# How can I make this function more efficient?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this data structure of credit card types.

It would be nice to make the hasTransFee more efficient.  If I started adding storecards etc to this list it could get quite big so the faster it works the better.

Anyone have any suggestions?

```
$scope.creditCards = [
    { name: 'VISA DEBIT/DELTA', value: 'DEL', transactionFee: false},
    { name: 'VISA CREDIT', value: 'VIS', transactionFee: true },
    { name: 'MASTERCARD CREDIT', value: 'MSC', transactionFee: true },
    { name: 'MASTERCARD DEBIT', value: 'MCD', transactionFee: false },
    { name: 'MAESTRO', value: 'MAE', transactionFee: false },
    { name: 'SWITCH', value: 'SWI', transactionFee: false },
    { name: 'VISA ELECTRON', value: 'ELC', transactionFee: false },
    { name: 'SOLO', value: 'SOL', transactionFee: false }
  ];


var hasTransFee = function(cardType) 
{
 for (var i=0; i < $scope.creditCards.length; i++) {
    if($scope.creditCards[i].value==cardType && $scope.creditCards[i].transactionFee == true){
     return true;   
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: If you are having problems with the performance of your code, do some profiling and identify where the slow parts are. Until then, you shouldn't be worrying about premature optimisation.

Comment: Sure looks like the `value` of each would make a nice object key, no? Then no loop is needed at all. It would just be like `card_values[cardType]`.

Comment: Set the value as the key of hash, then simply return creditCards[key].transactionFee. No iteration required

Comment: Performance is unlikely to be an issue until you get to at least 1,000 records. However, you can simply make a list of the cards with a transaction fee then do a search on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `value` is a unique identifier, if that's the case you could store the "credit cards" in an `object` instead, like this:

```
$scope.creditCards = {
    'DEL': { name: 'VISA DEBIT/DELTA', transactionFee: false},
    'VIS': { name: 'VISA CREDIT', transactionFee: true },
    'MSC': { name: 'MASTERCARD CREDIT', transactionFee: true }
  };
```

And then you don't even need a function for checking if the Credit Card has a `transactionFee`, if you still want to have a function, that function would look like this:

```
var hasTransFee = function(cardType){
  return $scope.creditCards[cardType].transactionFee;
}
```

Comment: `some` is always going to be slower than traditional for-loop, so there isn't any comparison :), it is just a better alternative for `forEach` when you need to stop iteration. The dictionary access is always going to be faster. I have used array (where need to maintain the sort order) along with properties added to the array for easy access to a specific index.

Answer (score -1):

*Side-note: This is better suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)*

Try this:

```
var hasTransFee = function(cardType)
{
    var thecard;
    $scope.creditCards.some(function(item) {
        return item.value == cardType && (thecard = item);
    });
    return thecard && thecard.transactionFee;
};
```

This will only iterate as far as it needs to in order to find the card with the right type, and no further (your original code will continue to scan the whole array if the card is found but has no fee).

**Important:** Only ONE `=` sign in `&& thecard = item`. It is deliberately an *assignment*, required to make the final `return` work.

Comment: Why would that be faster?

Comment: @squint Two reasons. 1: Stopping iteration when the desired card has been found prevents pointless processing. 2: Using built-in functions like `Array.prototype.some` will always be faster than the higher-level equivalent of a manual `for` loop.

Comment: His current code uses a `for` loop, and does a `return` when the match is found.

Comment: Here's a [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/for-loop-vs-some). `Array.prototypoe.some` is much slower. Also, you need parens around the `thecard` assignment`

Comment: Yes, but notice how if the match is found, *but it has no transaction fee*, the code will continue to loop through the other cards.

Comment: That should be handled by changing the condition. The same error could be made with `.some()`. Though I'd bet that the `for` is still faster on average even with that issue.